# Odd number of elements in hash assignment at /usr/share/pkg-config-dpkghook when adding an architecture for cross-compliation?

Tags: package-management, dpkg, compiling, perl

Someone suggested that I run `sudo dpkg --add-architecture armhf` to [add cross-compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61740356/how-to-cross-compile-a-binary-for-a-raspberry-pi-written-in-haskell-in-ubuntu-li) to my x86_64 box running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, but it doesn't appear to work:

```
$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture armhf
[sudo] password for leeand00:
Odd number of elements in hash assignment at /usr/share/pkg-config-dpkghook line 30.
```

The dpkghook (perl file) in question looks like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
#
# Sets up /usr/bin/*-pkg-config symlinks to point to the cross wrapper.
#
# It is called from dpkg --post-invoke and from postinst with the "update"
# argument to instate the necessary symlinks.
#
# It is called from prerm with the "remove" argument to remove all symlinks.
#

use strict;
use warnings;

use Dpkg::Arch qw(debarch_to_gnutriplet);
use Dpkg::ErrorHandling qw(error);

my $crosswrapper = "/usr/share/pkg-config-crosswrapper";

my $action = $ARGV[0];
error("parameter must be 'remove' or 'update'")
  unless defined $action && ($action eq "remove" || $action eq "update");

my $arch = `dpkg --print-architecture`;
error('dpkg --print-architecture failed') if $? >> 8;
my @architectures = `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`;
error('dpkg --print-foreign-architectures failed') if $? >> 8;
push @architectures, $arch;
chomp @architectures;

my %gnutriplets = map { debarch_to_gnutriplet($_) => 1 } @architectures;

my %symlinks = map { $_ => 1 } </usr/bin/*-pkg-config>;

foreach my $symlink (keys %symlinks) {
  $symlink =~ m,^/usr/bin/([^-]+-[^-]+-[^-]+)-pkg-config, or next;
  next if exists $gnutriplets{$1} && $action eq "update";
  next unless -l $symlink;
  next unless readlink $symlink eq $crosswrapper;
  unlink $symlink or
    error("failed to remove symlink $symlink: $!");
}

if ($action eq 'update') {
  foreach (keys %gnutriplets) {
    my $linktarget = "/usr/bin/${_}-pkg-config";
    next if exists $symlinks{$linktarget};
    next if -e $linktarget;
    symlink $crosswrapper, $linktarget or
      error("failed to create symlink $linktarget to $crosswrapper: $!");
  }
}
```

and line 30 looks like this:

`my %gnutriplets = map { debarch_to_gnutriplet($_) => 1 } @architectures;`

I don't really understand the package manager in Ubuntu apart from basic things like using `dpkg` to install / status / uninstall packages, so why am I seeing this error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I was able to debug the hook script. And while I was debugging it, I figured out, that I tried to add an unsupported architecture, in my case aarch64.

Try to run:

```
dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
```

In case you see a not supported architecture, try to remove it:

```
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture aarch64
```

At least this worked for me.

Comment: I accidentally added "i38" instead of "i386" but I still get the error when I try to remove it...

Comment: Temporarily making usr/share/pkg-config-dpkghook an empty file seems to help